# Ejabberd mysql prefix on database tables

Tags: mysql, database, xmpp, ejabberd

How can I use prefixes on database table names in Ejabberd? I have the mysql.sql file with the schema and I would to use the prefix "ejabberd_" on all the tables.

I can't seem to find anything on the documentation.

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/

Comment: What's wrong with it living within its own database?  Multiple database per mysql server is built-in.  Then you're just doing `ejabberd.table` instead of `ejabberd_table`.

Comment: In this case I want to have everything on the same database. Unfortunately simple table names like 'users' would conflict with the actual users table on my system. Anyways, if it's not possible, it'll just be installed on it's own database. It could be an option to the ejabberd configuration though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there is no option to define custom table prefixes.